# CSV file parse to Array Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, csv, nsarray

Hi I have a csv file and I would like to parse the information there on an array so I can use it on a map.
Heres is what I have from the parsing part:

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Geolocalizadas" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *content =  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"array: %@", content);
NSArray *arrayfarm = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
for (NSString *item in arrayfarm) {
    NSArray *itemArray = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    // log first item
    NSLog(@"%@",[itemArray objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

I use the nslog onthe content and array and always get (null)

Comment: If "content" is null/empty then your file access is mucked up.  Make use of "error" to find out what may be going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I see two potential problems with your program.

1. You are passing a `nil` argument to the `error:` parameter in your `stringWithContentsOfFile:` line.  If there's a possibility something might go wrong (and apparently there is), you should pass a real argument there so you can figure out what went wrong.
2. You're using `@"\r"` to separate strings in the file.  That's weird on a Mac (which I guess you're using since this question is about an Objective-C program), though I guess possible.  You might want that to be `@"\n"`.  Or `@"\r\n"`, I guess, if it's a DOS format file.

I made just a change for #2 above and ran your program with a test file and it seems to work fine - meaning your problem is likely with #1.  It can't find the file, can't open it because of a permissions problem, or something along those lines.

Comment: Yeah, you can use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]`, but that has a tendency to produce blank "components" between every line.  Plain old `\n` works better in virtually all cases I've run into.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the full path of the file to `NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`, not just a filename.

Where is this CSV file? Is it in the app bundle? The Documents folder? Create the full path based on its location.

Comment: the CSV file is on the supporting files I modify the code but still cant get it working

Comment: Try getting rid of the `inDirectory:` part of the `pathForResource:` call. Most likely the file is in the root of the resource bundle.

Comment: try that but still shows as null, aslo try a txt file but it couldn't find it

Comment: What does "pathForResource" return?

Comment: (Are you sure your file is in the bundle?  Find the emulator storage in Finder and see if the file is there.)

Comment: @HotLicks yes the file is on Copy Bundle Resources, I found the file on the finder also but still cant find it on the app

Comment: You found it INSIDE THE BUNDLE as "installed" on the simulator?

Comment: @darkjuso - Go to /Users/YourId/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/YourAppNumber/YourAppName.app, RMB on YourAppName.app, and select "Show package contents".  Verify that your file is listed.

Comment: @HotLicks the files were not there, I try moving them to the package contents and didn't worked

Comment: Open Xcode, find the file in the "navigator", open the "info explorer" or whatever it's called -- the right-hand window -- and search around until you find a checkbox that names your project.  That box should be checked, just as it is for all .m files (but no .h files).

Comment: ok I will try that, for now I manage to add the file but with another extension so for now I will stick to that, thanks anyways

Comment: @HotLicks I was trying what you told me about the "info explorer" but I couldn't find that option could you send me a screenshot of that.

Comment: @darkjuso - You always catch me at home where I'm on my Windoze box.

Comment: @HotLicks pure coincidence haha, take your time I wasn't expecting the answer right away.

Comment: Open Xcode.  In the left-hand "navigator" column, select your file.  Open the right-hand window (using the right-hand "view" button on the tool bar).  You should see a window that says "File Name:" and your file name at the top.  Down in the section labeled "Target Membership" will be one or more buttons, one for each build target in the project.  Make sure the button for your build target is checked.